# Exporting copy of workbook with formats and without formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with VBA code that exports copy whole workbook or multiple worksheets at time without formulas and retaining the formats. Source workbook should remain unchanged.

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate the workbook/worksheets, or do you intend to export them to PDF?

Comment: I am trying to duplicate the workbook without formulas and save  in .xlsx format.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you

Comment: What did you do to fix it?